# How to add an item to the top of the array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000]
```

I need:

[-100,10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000]

How to add an item to the top of the array in Python 3.4?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `list.insert(index, element)`

```
listA = [10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000]
listA.insert(0, -100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Below code will do..

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000]
a.insert(0,-100)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you should use the insert method.

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# to Add
alist.insert(0, 0)

print(alist)
```

The result will be

```
#/usr/bin/python3.4 test.py 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```